# Unmarshal JSON in go with different types in a list

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have trouble unmarschaling a JSON contruct:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "result": [
    {
      "bundled": true,
      "type": "RM-J1100"
    },
    [
      {
        "name": "PowerOff",
        "value": "AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAvAw=="
      },
      {
        "name": "Input",
        "value": "AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAlAw=="
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I actually need the second slice item from the result.

My current attempt is

```
type Codes struct {
    Id     int32      `json:"id"`
    Result []interface{} `json:"result"`
}

type ResultList struct {
    Info  InfoMap
    Codes []Code
}

type InfoMap struct {
    Bundled bool   `json:"bundled"`
    Type    string `json:"type"`
}

type Code struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}
```

the output is like:

```
{10 {{false } []}}
```

but I also tried to use this:

```
type Codes struct {
    Id     int32      `json:"id"`
    Result []interface{} `json:"result"`
}
```

the output is okay:

```
{10 [map[type:RM-J1100 bundled:true] [map[name:PowerOff value:AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAvAw==] map[name:Input value:AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAlAw==]]]}
```

I can also reference the Result[1] index:

```
[map[name:PowerOff value:AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAvAw==] map[name:Input value:AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAlAw==]]
```

But I fail to convert the interface type to any other Type which would match. Can anybody tell me how to do interface conversion. And what approach would be the "best".

Comment: Is this real world json? People make some ugly things.

Comment: Thats an json my Sony Bravia TV resturns if i query the possible controll codes. Of course it's stripped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option would be to unmarshal the top level thing into a slice of [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) initially.

Then loop through the members, and look at the first character of each one. If it is an object, unmarshal that into your `InfoMap` header struct, and if it is an array, unmarshal it into a slice of the `Code` struct.

Or if it is predictable enough, just unmarshal the first member to the one struct and the second to a slice.

I made a [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/W3DqVgDC3r) of this approach.

```
type Response struct {
    ID        int               `json:"id"`
    RawResult []json.RawMessage `json:"result"`
    Header    *Header           `json:"-"`
    Values    []*Value          `json:"-"`
}

type Header struct {
    Bundled bool   `json:"bundled"`
    Type    string `json:"type"`
}

type Value struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
    //error checks ommitted
    resp := &Response{}
    json.Unmarshal(rawJ, resp)
    resp.Header = &Header{}
    json.Unmarshal(resp.RawResult[0], resp.Header)
    resp.Values = []*Value{}
    json.Unmarshal(resp.RawResult[1], &resp.Values)
}
```

Comment: As seen in the playground. This is also working. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score -2):

*(I will not point out how horrific it is this JSON struct, but as always: sXXt happens)*

You can convert your struct like this, by using a cycle of JSON Marshal / Unmarshal. Code follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

const (
    inputJSON = `{
  "id": 10,
  "result": [
    {
      "bundled": true,
      "type": "RM-J1100"
    },
    [
      {
        "name": "PowerOff",
        "value": "AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAvAw=="
      },
      {
        "name": "Input",
        "value": "AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAlAw=="
      }
    ]
  ]
}`
)

type Codes struct {
    Id     int32          `json:"id"`
    Result [2]interface{} `json:"result"`
}

type Result struct {
    Info  InfoMap
    Codes []Code
}

type InfoMap struct {
    Bundled bool   `json:"bundled"`
    Type    string `json:"type"`
}

type Code struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
    newCodes := &Codes{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputJSON), newCodes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Prints the whole object
    log.Println(newCodes)

    // Prints the Result array (!)
    log.Println(newCodes.Result)

    if len(newCodes.Result) != 2 {
        log.Fatal("Invalid Result struct")
    }

    // Marshal and Unmarshal data to obtain the code list
    byteCodeList, _ := json.Marshal(newCodes.Result[1])

    codeList := make([]Code, 0)

    err = json.Unmarshal(byteCodeList, &codeList)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Invalid Code list")
    }

    // Prints the codeList
    log.Println(codeList)
}
```

Test it on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/p3Bw2NXYJv).

Comment: I already feared that i have to Marshal and Unmarshal the desired parts of the JSON, but i hoped there whould be an way to map an interface to other types and i wasn't that sure how to do it. Thanks

Comment: You should not need to Marshal and Unmarshal. This is exactly what json.RawMessage is for. See my answer.

Comment: I see you point and checking the golang documentation i see your point. In your example the codes does not marshal parts of the json twice. But doesn't it use more memory (which is not relevant in this example, just in principle)

Comment: Honestly I think the memory is about equal. When you unmarshal it for the intermediate step, you make another buffer that should be equivalent to the 2 raw messages in my struct. If you nil out those raw messages, they should get garbage collected just like your local buffers do here.